# How to create SOAPAdater using IBM worklight 6.2?

Tags: soap, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am trying to create Soap Adapter using IBM Work light but I am not able to get web services methods to work light projects Services folder. When I am running my project after deployment of adapter it will not showing proper output. Let me know if anyone had made demo or some good Links related to it.

Comment: @Idan..why you have down voted this question?

Comment: See my answer for my reasoning to the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have successfully consume weather Soap service.

Below given is main function which should call after successful connection.

```
function loadContactSuccess(result){

  WL.Logger.debug("Device is connected to WL server");
  WL.Logger.info("Inside loadContactSuccess" );

  var list = result.invocationResult.Envelope.Body.GetWeatherInformationResponse.GetWeatherInformationResult.WeatherDescription;
  console.log("list detail ..." + list);

  sessionStorage.setItem("WeatherDescription", JSON.stringify(result.invocationResult.Envelope.Body.GetWeatherInformationResponse.GetWeatherInformationResult.WeatherDescription));

  WL.Logger.debug("WeatherDescription list :: ", JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("WeatherDescription")));

  var tempValue = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("WeatherDescription"));

  console.log("Inside loadContactSuccess ..." + tempValue.length);
  text = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < tempValue.length; i++) { 
        text += tempValue[i].WeatherID +"      "+"<img src="+  tempValue[i].PictureURL +">" + "<br>";
    }     
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

}
```

You can also download demo example create by me from URL.[Click Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hexirvaxqzbrehq/HTTPAdapter.rar?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation does not provide the steps you have *actually* taken nor the expected output, the service you are using, the error you're getting, etc... so it is somewhat difficult to understand/recreate the issue... Also, please do mention the *build* number of the Worklight Studio 6.2 installation you're using.

---

There is no such thing as a "SOAP adapter" per-se. What you are referring to is "HTTP adapter" that is generated by providing a WSDL scheme location.

For example, WebServiceX.net provides a [global weather service](http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=12&WSID=56).
In order to generate an adapter from the above:

1. Create a new project
2. In the project structure, right-click on the `Services` folder and select "Discover back-end services"
3. From the "Service type" dropdown, select "Web Service Definition Language (WSDL)"
4. In the "URL" field paste "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL" and click on "Go"
5. From the "Select Service" table, select a service and click on "Finish"

The end result is a new HTTP adapter in the adapters folder called "SoapAdapter1", containing an auto-generated XML and -impl.js file ready to use.

You can read more about it, here:

- [HTTP adapters training module, slide #16](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf)
- [Generating adapters with the services discovery wizard](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_using_service_discovery_to_explore_back-end_services.html) user documentation topic

I also suggest using the very latest iFix available for the 6.2.0.1 release, as it contains some WSDL-related fixes, so best to be up-to-date.

It can be downloaded from either [IBM Fix Central](http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/) or from the Eclipse Marketplace (Eclipse > Help > Marketplace).

Comment: @Idan..thnx for yr answer. I am getting undefined type for result.invocationResult.Envelope.Body.GetWeatherInformationResponse.GetWeatherInformationResult.WeatherDescription.WeatherID...I am consuming http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx.

Comment: @nitishpatel can you please paste the code of the generated adapter JS (e.g. SoapAdapter1-impl.js?

Comment: @yossile..Thnx for help.. I have resolved that problem.

Comment: @nitishpatel I'm glad to hear.. Can you please add a line that describes the solution for future developers who may come across this question? Thanks